# Not able read json file loacted in app's resource folder on azure

Tags: java, spring, azure, spring-boot

I have spring boot app. I am trying to read json file which is located in my resource folder (using class loader). I have deployed my app on azure its giving me error no such file exist and when i print path it is giving me null.

Comment: Could you add the code that loads the file (along with the path)?

Comment: classLoader = getClass().getClassLoader();
  File file = new File(URLDecoder.decode(classLoader.getResource("tags.ser").getFile()));

Answer (score 0):

I tried to create a simple Maven project to fix your issue.

My source code structure is like below.

```
simpleMavenProj
   |-src/main/java/Hello.java
   |-src/main/resources/hello.json
```

The content of `Hello.java` is as below.

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.URL;

public class Hello {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        InputStream resourceInputStream = null;
        URL resourceURL = Hello.class.getClassLoader().getResource("resources/hello.json");
        if(resourceURL == null) {
            System.out.println("Get the InputStream of hello.json in IDE");
            resourceInputStream = new FileInputStream(Hello.class.getClassLoader().getResource("").getPath()+"../../src/main/resources/hello.json");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Get the InputStream of hello.json from runnable jar");
            resourceInputStream = Hello.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("resources/hello.json");
        }
        System.out.println();
        StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder();
        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(resourceInputStream));
        String line = null;
        while((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
            builder.append(line+"\n");
        }
        br.close();
        System.out.println(builder.toString());
    }
}
```

And `hello.json`:

```
{
    "hello":"world"
}
```

If you are developing in an IDE, run the code and the result is:

```
Get the InputStream of hello.json in IDE

{
    "hello":"world"
}
```

Else for generating a runable jar file, then to run the jar file via `java -jar simpleMavenProj.jar` and the result is:

```
Get the InputStream of hello.json from runnable jar

{
        "hello":"world"
}
```

Hope it helps. Any concern, please feel free to let me know.